# Trouble updating my MERN app, receiving a 404 Error on POST request

Tags: reactjs, mern

I am working on my first full-stack Mern app and I am able to GET data from the database but I'm having trouble with my POST request when trying to update a record from the database. I followed along with the MongoDB documentation to get set up but I'm unsure of the use of useParams.  Does the `id` need to be a string?  When I added `${params.id.toString()}` to the end of the fetch url I received another error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
```

When trying to submit with code as seen below I receive this error:

```
POST http://localhost:4000/update/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

My Route:

```
// This section will help you update a record by id.
plantRoutes.route("/update/:id").put(function (req, response) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("plant-babies-data");
  let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) };
  let newvalues = {
    $set: {
      waterDate: req.body.waterDate
    },
  };
  db_connect
    .collection("plants")
    .updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document updated");
      response.json(res);
    });
});
```

My POST request from front-end component:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router";

const params = useParams();

// update database 
 async function submitData(id) {
   const editedDate = {
     waterDate: updatedPlant
   };
    // This will send a post request to update the data in the database.
   await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/update/${params.id}`, {
     method: "POST",
     body: JSON.stringify(editedDate),
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
   });
   console.log(`item with id ${id} updated`);
 }
```

Comment: `/update/undefined` means id not passed correctly. Try log out `params.id` and see the output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I log out ```params.id``` it says undefined.  If I just log out ```id``` it gives me the id of the item I want to update. But I also receive error if I use just ```${id}``` for my POST request: ```POST http://localhost:4000/update/0 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: If you can access item id, why not directly use it, instead of using the router's `param.id`.

Comment: In order for me to use the item id, how would I then change the route?  I tried using the item id and route as is and received another 404 error.  Then I tried removing the ```params``` from the route changing route to ```let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.id) };``` and also to ```let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(id) };``` both received 404 error: ```POST http://localhost:4000/update/0 404 (Not Found)```

Comment: After changing my code to only using ```id``` and not ```params.id``` and changing the route to ```let myquery = { _id: ObjectId(req.id) };``` I'm not getting the 404 error anymore. It appears that my POST request is at least not throwing an error- although my database is not reflecting new data.  I'm wondering if my date format is incorrect or if my state is not working as I would like.